# What is the schema of the data stores used by the reference client?

Tags: wallet, bitcoin-core, database, peers

I'm interested in seeing the schema (layout and indexes) that is used in the reference client.  Namely wallet.dat, the bk** files and also the in-memory uncommitted tx.

Does this exist anywhere for the 7.x client or the newer BerkleyDB format?

I'd like to see what, if any changes are being made to accommodate [BIP 0034](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/BIP_0034).

Answer (score 1):

There are the [bitcoin-tools by Gavin Andresen](https://github.com/gavinandresen/bitcointools) but they will only work up to version 0.7 of Bitcoin-QT. If your goal is to simply check whether the blocks are version 1 or 2 I suggest you do something like this:

```
MAX_HEIGHT=`bitcoind getinfo | grep blocks | grep -oE '[0-9]+'`
MIN_HEIGHT=210000
for HEIGHT in `seq $MAX_HEIGHT -1 $MIN_HEIGHT`; do
  HASH=`bitcoind getblockhash $HEIGHT`
  VERSION=`bitcoind getblock $HASH | grep version | grep -oE '[0-9]+'`
  echo $HEIGHT,$HASH,$VERSION
done >> block-versions.csv
```

This will get you a Comma-Separated file with the block's height,its hash and version.